# How do I upload reviews in bulk to Magento via .CSV

Tags: magento, csv

I work for a company who recycle books on behalf of charities. We are attempting to create a book store using the Magento ecommerce system. We have managed to upload books and images with a .CSV file, but I can not figure out how to upload reviews in bulk.

We will be utilising Nielsen Record Supply, and so will be downloading something in the region of 10,000 reviews, so I would presume .CSV would be the best way of going about this.

Is it possible to store them in the installation folder somewhere perhaps?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write your own import script. The easiest way to do this if you're not familiar with Magento is probably to just insert them in the database using a script. I'd suggest to take a look at the tables which are prefixed `review` and ask more specific questions if you encounter any problems writing the script :).